# Performance on EJB Container Managed Transaction VS Bean Managed Transaction

Tags: ejb, containers

Regarding on comparison between EJB Container Managed Transaction and Bean Managed Transaction?

- Which one has got better performance.
- Best practice on when to use either of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wether to choose among BMT and CMT depends on the business decision, rather than performance.

In my opinion there's no best practices, however these are some examples for preferring one or the other.

BMT

1. You have a `Stateful` bean, and the global commit depends on the results of other methods. By using BMT with `Stateful`, you can infact leave the transaction open, and close/commit it when your business decision has been made.
2. For any reason you want to have full control on your transaction boundaries

CMT

1. You have a `Stateful` and you want to implement the SessionSynchronization interface for knowing when transaction begin end etc... In this case your bean has to use CMT
2. You have a chain of EJBs and you want all them to be part of a single transaction, in this case you need to use CMT (although the first ejb can initiate and share its BMT transaction).

There are some scenarios where the usage of BMT has something to consider.

1. If you use BMT with `MessageDriven` the message is not part of the transaction, so the message is acknowledged by the container.
2. If you an EJB and a method with BMT, that method cannot join an existing transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Bean Managed Transaction should be a little faster than Container Managed Tansaction.

CMT needs to do some extra work, which does not need to be done in BMT.

- The container must check if a transaction is already started.
- The container must read the @TransactionAttribute annotation of the method.
- The container must start a new Transaction (in case of TransactionAttributeType:  Required, RequiresNew) before running the method or throw an Exception (in case of TransactionAttributeType: Never, Mandatory).